# Redirect to home url but remember first url

Tags: php, redirect

I am making a website for a client of mine, and it is quite complicated. It consists of a sidescrolling parallax style story and the pages are filled with a lightbox system. So when you click a link it wont go to another page but opens it in the lightbox.

Here comes the problem:
It works when you go to www.foo.com. But I want when you go to www.foo.com/subpage, it redirects to the homepage and opens the selected subpage in the lightbox. I have the code to open the lightbox from a variable. But I dont know how to fetch the url you typed.

Comment: Maybe an ajax call to that page and load the data?

Comment: Check out `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, it contains the URL. Store it in a session, or add it to the URL you go to as an argument.

Comment: that could be possible. But how do I redirect to home and grab the first url @Marco Mura

Comment: Sorry, you're not making sense. (to me). You will always have to 'grab' the URL before the redirect.

Comment: edited first comment. You came between but was comment to first commenter

Comment: Check the referer `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But how about do not track plugins.. Would that be a problem

Comment: No, the notrack plugin o browser cannot stop $_SERVER[] variables in php. The internet has to work in normal way. i thin "no track" if i understood good, is more than a courtesy request from browser.

Comment: Anyway some script sample from your problem would help.

Comment: Na no examples needed, just comment the hell out of this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

via php.
should be the URL you came from.